# Expo location always returning wrong and unacurate location on android

Tags: react-native, expo, geolocation

In IOS everything works fine but when trying to fetch user current location expo-location always return the same wrong and unacurate location.

Here's my code:

```
const location = await getCurrentPositionAsync( {
  accuracy: Accuracy.Balanced
  distanceInterval: 100,
  timeInterval: 1000 * 120 // 2min as MS
} )
console.log( location )

// output 
{"coords": {"accuracy": 2000, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 0, "latitude": xxx, "longitude": xxx, "speed": 0}, "mocked": false, "timestamp": 1690919435627}
```

Things I've already tryed:

- changing to `Accuracy.High` or `Accuracy.Highest`
- deleted `node_modules`, `.expo` and `android` folders and rebuilding the app
- decreasing `timeInterval` and `distanceInterval`
- restarting android phone
- uninstalling the app from the phone
- using `getLastKnownPositionAsync({ maxAge: 1000 * 120, requiredAccuracy: 100 })`

One thing I've noticed is that `latitude` and `longitude` are always the same, They haven't changed in any moment. In IOS, these values changes as is the expected behavior.

Is there anything else I'm missing? Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you on a VPN or proxy service?

Comment: @Abe I'm not using VPN nor proxy... and it is working on IOS in same wifi as android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that I was missing to add `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` inside expo app.config.js:

```
expo: {
  ...
  android: {
    permissions: [
      ...,
      'ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'
    ]
  }
}
```

After adding this line and running `expo prebuild` everything started working fine.